# How to Import .JSON file into Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I currently use Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0. And I've downloaded dataset from the internet.

[image]

Seems like I successfully imported the .JSON file. But the tables are not the same. And there is only one table in the dataset that I downloaded. In SQL developer, there are dozens of tables that I can't understand.

[image]

**What should I do?**

*[Process of importing .JSON file]*

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

XE is the created one.

Comment: Who are you logged in as?

Comment: With created account while installation

Comment: So SYS? Don't use that schema for tables, it's reserved for the database, create your own.

Comment: I don't remember the first I created. Instead, I created once again, where I used SYSTEM for name & password. Seems like I need to create my own.

Comment: I'd like to see how you imported the JSON file

Comment: Yes, sir, I edited the question so that you can see the process of importing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the json file is just for the connection details to a database, and the xml might define the tables. Or the tables have been created during installation process of the database by the DBA.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31159655)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Command Line documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/sql-developer-command-line/23.2/sqcug/import-connections.html#GUID-05EB003F-4BA6-4729-A091-3A85B5EA0419), it looks like it's something you can do from there.  If not, check your GUI's version and make sure it's the latest.